# I don't want access base class methods on extends class

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have two typscript classes.

**CodeManagementApi.ts**

```
module Erkyazilim.CodeManagementApi {
    export class Api extends WebApiBase {
        public static list(callbackDone: (res: Model.ResultList<Model.DtoFileManager>) => void, callbackFail: (res: any) => void = null, contentType = 'application/json', opts: JQueryAjaxSettings = null) { 
            //I want access ajaxHelper method only this here.
            super.ajaxHelper(`/api/CodeManagementApi/List`, 'POST', null, callbackDone, callbackFail, contentType, opts); 
        }
    }
}
```

**code-management.ts**

I don't want access ajaxHelper method from code-management.ts file. I want only access and see from CodeManagementApi.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'code-management'
})
export class CodeManagement implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    _http = Erkyazilim.CodeManagementApi.Api;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        //I don't want see this here. Only want see and access from CodeManagementApi.ts file
        this._http.ajaxHelper();
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: Object): void {}

    ngOnDestroy(): void {}    
}
```

**WebApiAjax.ts**

```
module Erkyazilim {
    export class WebApiBase {
        protected static ajaxHelper<TModel, TResult>(address: string,
            type: 'POST' | 'GET' | 'PUT' | 'PATCH' | 'DELETE',
            model: TModel,
            callbackDone: (res: TResult) => void,
            callbackFail: (res) => void,
            contentType: string,
            opts: JQueryAjaxSettings) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. `_http.ajaxHelper` won't be accessible inside `CodeManagement` class.

Comment: I don't want see `ajaxHelper()` method in `CodeManagement` class.

Comment: The code you posted won't compile because `ajaxHelper` is not accessible inside `CodeManagement `.

Comment: Yes right, but I see `ajaxHelper` method in `code-management.ts` in visual studio 2015. Maybe, this is a visual studio bug. You think?